# How to render a smooth path given a set of data points?

Tags: iphone, path, render, interpolation

I've been puzzling over path rendering for the past couple of days without any real solution.

By path rendering I mean given a set of x,y data points (at varying distance) to draw a dashed line (or in my case a rotated quad) of fixed length at regular intervals between the give data set points to create a smooth path.

If you have flight control for the iPhone I'm trying to create a similar effect to the path rendering in that game.

Here's my problem. If the width of the graphic + the gap is not devisable exactly in to the distance between the 2 dataset points I am then left with an overlap or underlap. My only solution to this is either

1) Take the overlap/underlap point to be the end point of the next data set point and then draw from there to the following point.

2) Always draw under the final endpoint and start a fresh from the next data point.

Neither of these solutions are ideal and both have problems.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Any help would be much appreciated.

The following screen illustrates what I'm trying to create : http://www.firemint.com/flightcontrol/screenshots-peaceful.html

The thick dotted line.

Update:

Hi I tried rendering via curves, I calculated a cubic curve (via 4 control points). However the problem is one of interpolation. Given 0 and 1 I can step through any 2 points. However I want to step through the entire path (multiple control points). The problem is that some control points will be a different distance apart, and thus steping through at a constant stepping increment (say 0.2) will produce irregular results. I realise in order to correctly step through the entire path I'd need to calculate the length of the entire curve ... question is how do I do that? ... or is there another way?

Cheers
Rich

Comment: did you ever find a solution on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

There's a CoreGraphics function called "CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint" that's used for drawing smooth paths.  [An example on how to use it is on GitHub](http://github.com/below/iphone-bezierdemo/tree).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I get home. Tell me, is thing that can be done in Open GLES? As I know a lot of the CoreGraphics stuff doesn't work in Open GLES.

Comment: @Rich it can be integrated with OpenGL to the same extent that any CoreGraphics stuff can be integrated with OpenGL.  I have no experience on the matter. =)

Comment: I didn't think you could render core graphics stuff ontop of an open gl es surface???

Comment: The link now appears to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) or [hermite curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_curve)  they are not that hard to calculate and you get nice soft curves.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check out [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and [Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_curve) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely restricted to fixed-size quads?  The ideal solution is to truncate the last quad to the correct size.

If you are restricted, you could do a couple things.  If you're drawing dashed lines you can vary the distance of the dashes in order to make sure you never end up with partial quads on the endpoints.  This might be visually distracting as the distance would adjust based on the length of the segment.

edit:

Ah, the picture helps.  I assume since this is on the iPhone that you're getting a series of points from which drawing lines between them produces an acceptable curve.  If this is the case using splines/curve primitives is probably overkill.  I would probably approach drawing lines as shown simply by drawing quads at every data point that is a given distance from the last data point.

The algorithm would be something like:

1. Draw quad on the first data point (rotated appropriately)
2. Traverse the point list until you're at least X distance from the last point
3. Lerp between the current point and the last visited point to find the exact center to place the next quad.
4. Draw the quad (rotated appropriately)
5. Go to step 2
6. If you have a partial point for the last quad draw it as normal (this will give a better visual than truncating it).

For fun, to lerp between two points by some distance D that is less than the distance between the two points (this is probably more simple in the 2D case but I like to work generally):

```
vector v = point2 - point1;
normalize(v);
v *= D;
finalPoint = point1 + v;
```

Comment: I only accept data points that are a given distance from the current one, so my collation of points will have a minimum distance. Which is the same distance as my rotated graphic. However if the user moves their finger quickly the distance between the points becomes large (hence the interpolating). Could you please detail the Lerping part a little more, as this sounds similar to what I'm currently doing, and this does not produce as smooth path as in the screen shot.

Comment: The method I described only looks good if you have data points that are no farther apart than 2 times the distance between your dashes.  If your data points are farther than that you'll need to investigate a curve fitting method (the standard curve fitting for a problem like this tends to be Catmull-rom) as your curve will begin to flatten out.

Comment: In reference to the interpolation, since often your data point will not be exactly on top of where you want to draw the quad, you'll need to go somewhere between two of your data points.  When you know which two you want to be between, you can apply a linear interpolation (solve the equation of the line between the two points for some interpolation constant based on how far along the line the quad should be) or if they are farther, apply a curve-approximation interpolation (as I mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the user moves their finger quickly the datapoints will be further than twice the distance of the dashes. I think this is looking more and more like a curve interpolation job.